# Ranking records according to timestamp but omit records where the time difference is less than 30 minutes

Tags: sql, ranking, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon Redshift SQL querying, I try to sort the records according to 3 columns: timestamp, cookieID, trackingpointID, but when the time difference between the two records ordered by this 3 columns is less than 30 minutes (with the same cookieID and trackingpoint), I want to omit this records and leave just the highest, for example if I would have:

```
timestamp   cookie  track
9:04:29     A       10420641
9:04:32     A       10420641
9:04:36     A       10420641
9:04:32     A       10420641
10:30:00    A       10420641
10:31:21    A       10420641
9:07:01     A       10881111
9:07:34     A       10881111
9:07:45     A       10881111
9:04:39     A       4326086
```

And I would like to have a result as this:

```
timestamp   cookie  track       row
9:04:36     A       10420641    1
10:31:21    A       10420641    2
9:07:45     A       10881111    1
9:04:39     A       4326086     1
```

Comment: What if you have ten records, all separated by 25 minutes?

Comment: If you put `...` after your last line in the result it becomes much more obvious what you want, now it seems like you just want those 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to sessionize your data.  You can do this with `lag()` and cumulative sums.  Something like this:

```
select min(timestamp), cookie, track, sessionid
from (select r.*, sum(IsSessionStart) over (partition by cookie, track order by timestamp) as sessionid
      from (select r.*,
                   (case when datediff(min,
                                       lag(timestamp) over (partition by cookie, track order by timestamp),
                                       timestamp) > 30
                         then 1 else 0 end) as IsSessionStart
            from records r
           ) r
     ) r
group by cookie, track, sessionId;
```